# Python Mechanize with Dynamic Dropdown Selection

Tags: python, webforms, drop-down-menu, mechanize

I'm using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to fill forms and I run into a problem with dynamically-filled dropdown lists that are dependent on a previous selection.

In mechanize, I do something like this to select the category:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
"""Select the form and set up the browser"""
br["state"] = ["California"]
br["city"] = ["San Francisco"] # this is where the error is
br.submit()
```

I cannot choose the city as "San Francisco" until I have chosen the state as "California," because the city dropdown list is dynamically populated after choosing "California."

How can I submit the city with Python and mechanize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mechanize doesn't support JavaScript. Instead, you should use urllib2 to send the desired values.

```
import urllib2
import urllib

values = dict(state="CA", city="SF") # examine form for actual vars
try:
    req = urllib2.Request("http://example.com/post.php",
                          urllib.urlencode(values))
    response_page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, details:
    pass #do something with the error here...
```

Comment: This would submit, wouldn't it?  I suppose this would mean I can't do it in mechanize, since I need Javascript.  I also don't see how urllib2 supports Javascript, because from your example, it still wouldn't be able to pick out the city

Comment: @Lionel - No, you'd have to know ahead of time how the JavaScript populates the dropdown. It shouldn't be too hard to examine the JavaScript and create the post values it does.

Comment: Good point, I'll study the Javascript to get the post values.